# How to get Mat with a drawable input in Android using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, drawable, mat, highgui

I have some image files in the drawable folder. And now, I want to convert them into opencv Mat object. I've found a function:

```
Mat img = Highgui.imread(inFile);
```

which is reading a file path to get the Mat.

However, I can't get path of my images as I can only read them by using their id like R.drawable.img1.

How could I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do

```
Mat img = Utils.loadResource(context, refrenceimgID, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gryimg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);
```

Comment: what's `gryimg`?