# How to set "context" for loadResource() to load a drawable image

Tags: android, opencv, android-drawable, android-context

i'm trying to open a jpeg file which is a drawable of my app. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184215/how-to-get-mat-with-a-drawable-input-in-android-using-opencv) method I have no idea about how to set the variable "context" (that is the first parameter of the function loadResource).

My aim is just to load this image, extract some feature and compare it with the frames grabbed from camera. And to this end I would like some good suggested tutorial (i will use some feature matching method).

thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't know what a `context` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn more about [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

Use `getApplicationContext()`:

```
Mat img = Utils.loadResource(getApplicationContext(), refrenceimgID, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Or if your code is on an activity, use `this`:

```
Mat img = Utils.loadResource(this, refrenceimgID, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

or `YourActivityName.this`:

```
Mat img = Utils.loadResource(YourActivityName.this, refrenceimgID, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Comment: thanks with getApplicationContext() it works!... i know that because i write a text with the sizes of the loaded image on the image frame grabbed from camera (i'm working in the onCameraFrame function)... but now if i want to show this image instead of the one grabbed from camera (simply by make the function return this new Mat) it doesn't work (i see black screen)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in Activity scope just write `this`:

```
Mat img = Utils.loadResource(this, refrenceimgID, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Imgproc.cvtColor(img, gryimg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2BGRA);
```

If you are in Fragment scope use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

Answer (score 0):

Just use your `Activity instance` as `MainActivity.this` where you need `Context`.

Or you can use your ApplicationClass instance as well.

Read about Context [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
Context c= this;
Resources res2 = c.getResources();
Drawable drawable = res2.getDrawable(R.drawable.YOUR_DRAWABLE_NAME);
```