# I am working with OpenCV while writing a simple method of imread, I cannot get it to read an image from my res/drawable folder

Tags: java, android, opencv

`[the mainActivity of my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPjdY.png)
[Implementational class which have the method to read the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNVLM.png)

```
**build.gradle(:app)**
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:3.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0'
    //implementation project(path: ':openCV')
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

```
**
AndroidManifest.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I want the imread() method to read the image but it is not reading it. The app is continuously showing that it cannot read the image. I'm new with openCV and androidstudio, Please help me out. I haven't made nay progress in past 2 days because of this issue.

Comment: Please do not use images of code. Does this answer your question? [Android Studio How to read image file in OpenCV using resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917772/android-studio-how-to-read-image-file-in-opencv-using-resources)

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thankyou soooooooo much. You have solved a huge problem for me man. I can't thank you enough man. Thankyou so muchhhh again. Also, It was my first question so i'm sorry I used images of code. Thankyou so much.